# Has the PD1 exam cancelled till end of February?

Tags: certification, platform-developer-1

I had registered for PD1 exam on 14th January. I received mail that it has been cancelled and will be again available by end of February and they've sent me coupan code for taking the exam later.

This is not updated in webassesor profile. Is this reliable and should I not go to center on 14th January for giving exam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding webassesor, I think it gets cancelled on the day of scheduled certification automatically. At least for me it was like that - PD1 cancellation announcement came on friday, certification was cancelled on monday - the day of scheduled certification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. As written in email the Questions of PD1 is leaked so Salesforce cancel all the scheduled exam.

How do I know, I know because my exam also got cancelled. So for now we have to wait.

Comment: **Question of PD1 leaked**: Salesforce got to know so late. It's been years people were giving exams by referring to dumps. Here are some sample questions from by [blog](http://www.rohitmourya.com/2017/05/salesforce-certified-platform-developer.html).

Comment: @RohitMourya yes its looks like they are late here.

Comment: @RohitMourya Are the questions you posted on your blog from the actual exam?

Comment: 90% of them are. Recently Salesforce updated PD1 questions so as of now I'm not sure about them.